# What is the best method to display error message in the same login form

Tags: javascript, php, html, session

I have a login.php file and a login_process.php file. My login form is in the first file and validation in the other. I do not know how to display error messages in the login form in login.php after validation in login_process.php.

I have been researching and below is what I've found :

(Note : I have multiple error messages and I use selection to display those messages)

1. Using `header('Location:login.php?submit=conError')` to redirect to the login.php file and in that file, use `$_GET` to retrieve the query
2. Using `header('Location:login.php#conError')`to redirect to the login.php and file in that file, use `location.hash` in javascript to retrieve the fragment
3. By including login_process.php in login.php and declare some variables and use `PHP_SELF` to use those variables to display error
4. Some use global session variable `$_SESSION['error']`

Which is better and safer? Which method does developer use the most? Can somebody help clarify? Is there a better way than ways mentioned above (in terms of security and optimum run time)?

Comment: @GoojajiGreg About your [(suggestive) edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/21500747) and the comment you left: "This question is PHP related only.". I beg to differ. The OP wants to display a message and it can be done with languages other than PHP including the ones the OP originally chose. The tags are relevant and I've added another, being "javascript" and "sessions", also being relevant to the question.

Comment: This question is too broad and probably opinion-based. In terms of security and sessions; look up "sessions middle-man" and "sessions security" on the Web.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use session option which is better way to show messages as most frameworks like codeigniter laravel and cms like WordPress opecart uses this approach.

And the sending error in URL doesn't seems good for the look of the application. If this is not a case for you then go ahead and change.

But I think message that we want to show almost includes in every page so it is better idea toh use session you dont need to pass it in URL.

Use session to store after displaying use unset to remove the message.

And with that you also ensuring to get rid of the burden of different names of variables for message on each page. You have single session variable which will do it for your whole application.

Answer (score 0):

I think sending the error in the URL is easy and it is used in many applications. Error message is not a sensitive information. I think you should try the first method.